# theres a way to automatically import all imports you need in contract (that are on your computer) to remix ide

Tags: solidity, remix, import

I have a remix ide contract and somehow I added all the imports automatically from my computer files im assuming. Does anyone know how to replicate this as i am trying to do it again and cannot find anything anywhere. I know this is possible because I just did it, and saw a bunch of notifications pop up at the bottom of remix saying importing all files.

Comment: might have been directly from github though

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for remind.

It will load your local files into remix.

https://github.com/ethereum/remixd

Hope it helps.